# Protobuf with Angular 2.0 and asp.net core(webpack) and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, protobuf.js

protobuf.js version: "protobufjs": "6.8.8",

i am new to protobufjs and planning to implement the protobufjs in Angular 2 project.
I have installed the protobufjs using the "npm install protobufjs --save" inside the Angular 2 project(VS2015).

i have the service below, which sends the http request to Restful service with Content-Type: application/x-protobuf and get the response in protobuf format

```
getpersondetails(): Observable {
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
return this.http.get('/system/data/getpersondetails', { headers });
}
```

Get the sample response as below,
↵*����Alex"(�0�↵&����Du���2355"

how to decode the response to below model object

```
//PerosnDetails.ts
export class PersonDetails
{
firstname:string;
lastname:string;
salary: number;
}
```

Can someone help me by providing some samples with descriptive steps for Get request in Angular 2 and typescript.

Any help are really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You want the raw (binary) response, so you have to set the option `responseType: "arraybuffer"`:

```js
http.get('/system/data/getpersondetails', { 
  headers,
  responseType: "arraybuffer"
});
```

Then you can deserialize your message from the array buffer:

```js
let details = PersonDetails.deserializeBinary(yourArrayBuffer);
```

But I recommend to use either gRPC-web or Twirp for two reasons:

1. you can use `service` declarations in your .proto and can get your clients generated for you
2. you have some standard for URL mapping and error handling

Also important: There are great alternatives to google-protobuf. For example ts-proto.
Or [protobuf-ts](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts) (this is a shameless plug, I am the author). It has [support for Angular](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts/blob/26594209b5120e32e599fa8c00ac4b2ccbd9952d/MANUAL.md#angular-support).